# Adding Html link in MailMessage Object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, email

I want to provide a link within Mail Message object. Tried googling couldnot find something which is simple and better. 
I have the following code

```
    public ActionResult Register(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var count = db.Customers.Where(x => x.Email == customer.Email).Count();
            if (count > 0)
            {
                @ViewBag.Error = "This mail already exists";
                return View();
            }
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            MailMessage msgobj = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient serverobj = new SmtpClient();
            serverobj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(customer.Email,customer.Password);
            serverobj.Port = 587;
            serverobj.Host = "Smtp.gmail.com";
            serverobj.EnableSsl = true;
            msgobj.From = new MailAddress(customer.Email, "Shopper's Stop", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            msgobj.To.Add(customer.Email);
            msgobj.Subject = "Account Activate Link";                
            msgobj.Body = GetFormattedMessageHTML(customer);
            msgobj.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msgobj.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
            serverobj.Send(msgobj);
            return RedirectToAction("Products", "Home");
        }
        return View();
    }
    private String GetFormattedMessageHTML(Customer customer)
    {
        return "<!DOCTYPE html> " +
            "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" +
            "<head>" +
                "<title>Email</title>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body style=\"font-family:'Century Gothic'\">" +
                "<h1 style=\"text-align:center;\"> " + "</h1>" +
                "<h2 style=\"font-size:14px;\">" +
                    "Name : " + customer.First_Name + " " + customer.Last_Name + "<br />" +
                    "Company : " + "NewTech Software" + "<br />" +
                    "Email : " + customer.Email + "<br />" +
                    //similar to this
                    //and when clicked how to perform further action
                    "Activation Link" + "<a href="+"some link"+"sometext to be clicked"+customer.Cust_Id +"></a>"+
                "</h2>" +                    
            "</body>" +
            "</html>";
    }
```

Can anyone plz help me. Above code is working fine but I am unable to generate link and also what else shoud be passed aong with cust_Id to verify upon click.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Replace

```
"<a href="+"some link"+"sometext to be clicked"+customer.Cust_Id +"></a>"
```

to

```
   "<a href=\""+your_url+"\">clickable text</a>"
```

and here     `string your_url="";`